# How Cassandra DateTieredCompactionStrategy identifies my data timestamp?

Tags: cassandra

New to Cassandra, I just read the blog about Cassandra [DTCS](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/datetieredcompactionstrategy).

Supose I have a table like this for example,

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
   id text,
   t1 timestamp,
   t2 timestamp,
   bar text,
   PRIMARY KEY (id,t1)
);
```

Looks like the only thing I need to do to enable DTCS is

```
ALTER TABLE <table> WITH compaction = {
    'class': 'DateTieredCompactionStrategy',
    'timestamp_resolution':'<resolution>', 'base_time_seconds':'3600',
    'max_sstable_age_days':'365'};
```

Is that true? Then how dose cassandra know which field of my data is the timestamp I expect to be used for DTCS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't use the value of any of your "fields".

Every non-key column has an associated [writetime](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_writetime.html), which is what the strategy uses.

This can be set manually with a `USING TIMESTAMP` clause, or will be set automatically to the time of the update/insert/delete.

Therefore, you may now find you don't actually need `t2` in your schema, but can just use the writetime of `bar`.